# Weather API (RESTful) giving error

Tags: jquery, web-services, rest, asp.net-web-api

I am using a simple web API to get weather details for the city **London**. However, I am not getting the required response but instead a **401 Error**. Am I doing anything wrong?

**HTML**

```
<html> 
<head> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "get",
            url: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function(data) {
                    //What to do on success 
            }
        });
    });
});
</script> 
</head> 

<body>
    <button>Click Me</button>
</body> 

</html>
```

**Using the following api**

http://openweathermap.org/current

**ERROR**

[image]

Comment: Calling that URL I get this response: `{"cod":401, "message": "Invalid API key. Please see http://openweathermap.org/faq#error401 for more info."}` Are you passing a valid API key in the request? http://openweathermap.org/faq#error401

Comment: Pls see the attached page and documentation. I picked the url from there only.

Comment: The documentation states that you need to have an API key to use it: http://openweathermap.org/appid. Also note that on a free account you are rate limited to how many times you call the API. If you need to rely on this service for your website I would suggest you pay for an SLA

Comment: Yes, I see now. I got the key ... now trying again.

Comment: I've got a key say : 12345. Now can you pls tell how to pass it?

Comment: It tells you right in the documentation page I linked you to

Comment: http://openweathermap.org/faq#error401 : Only tells to register a key. I got it, but where is it written how to use it? ;(

Comment: http://openweathermap.org/appid -> `API call:

http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/city?id=524901&APPID={APIKEY}
Parameters:

APPID {APIKEY} is your unique API key `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the keys as a querystring to the URL of the weather api.

You can add a small function to do this:

```
var url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/city';
var keys = {
    id: 524901,
    APPID: 12345 // Put your key here
}; 

function makeUrl (url, queryStringObject) {
    var query = [];
    // Loops through each key
    for(var key in queryStringObject){
        query.push(encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' +
            encodeURIComponent(queryStringObject[key]));
    }
    // Returns the url with the keys appended
    return url + (query.length ? '?' + query.join('&') : '');
}
```

This will return a key in the format required by the api:

```
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/city?id=524901&APPID=12345
```

Then in your call to the api, you can use the function call:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "get",
            url: makeUrl(url, keys), // Gets the constructed url
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function(data) {
                    //What to do on success 
            }
        });
    });
});
```